# IntelliJ cannot locate a test package

Tags: intellij-idea

I am having an issue getting IntelliJ to successfully locate a specific test package, named [company prefix].util.db. I am attempting to import a class from this package in a unit test in another module. The package exists under a test source folder but does not have a parallel under the regular source folders (both test and regular package structures for this module contain [company prefix].util packages but there is a [company prefix].util.db package only in the test package). The unit test runs just fine via ant but for some reason IntelliJ just refuses to see the import as valid.

The error seems to indicate that the [company prefix].util part of the import is valid but the db subpackage cannot be found. How can I help IntelliJ to see the classes I need?

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: I am not, I am using ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a dependency on a library, even with a test-scope dependency, only the *production* classes are included on the classpath, because the test code doesn't get added to the production jar.

To depend on resources (classes, whatever) from a test folder, you must have the classes you want packaged into a library that can be depended on with a test scope. To do this *we* use the maven jar plugin to generate a test-jar (in our case we are only interested in sharing a single class, but you can play with the includes list to suit yourself):

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
               <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>org/company/web/ValidatorTestUtils.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then our dependency carries both the test scope and the type:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.company.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-web</artifactId>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This makes the test class from the core-web module available to the dependent module's tests.

Comment: Alas, I was afraid that this might be the case but I didn't want to just assume limitations as IntelliJ has surprised me with hidden features before. I'm using ant, but I suppose I'll just have to find a way around it as best I can. Thanks